# How do I accumulate a sequence of digits in a string and convert them to one number?

Tags: python, string

I need to decode a string 'a3b2' into 'aaabb'. The problem is when the numbers are double,triple digits. E.g. 'a10b3' should detect that the number is **not** 1 but 10.

I need to start accumulating digits.

```
a = "a12345t5i6o2r43e2"
for i in range(0, len(a)-1):
  if a[i].isdigit() is False: 
   #once i see a letter, i launch a while loop to check how long a digit streak

   #after it can be - it's 2,3,4,5 digit number etc
    print(a[i])
    current_digit_streak = ''
    counter = i+1
    while a[counter].isdigit():  #this gives index out of range error!
      current_digit_streak += a[counter]
      counter+=1
```

If I change the while loop to this:

```
while a[counter].isdigit() and counter < ( len(a)-1)
```

it does work but omits the last letter.
I should not use regex, only loops.

Comment: You say you should only use loops, but in your code example you also use conditionals, arithmetic, and assignment! /s

Comment: @AdamSmith, sorry :) I mean i should use loops and other BASIC structures as you mentioned, just not those itertools, groupby etc.

Comment: regex is a very basic structure. I think it's necessary to actually see the problem statement of your homework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `for` loop and `while` loop use different indices for obtaining tokens, which is why the characters consumed by the `while` loop are processed once again by the `for` loop. You should instead use a `while` loop with a single index to parse the tokens:

```
a = "a12t5i6o2r11e2"
i = 0
char = repeat = output = ''
while i < len(a):
    token = a[i]
    if token.isdigit():
        repeat += token
    if char and repeat and (not token.isdigit() or i == len(a) - 1):
        output += char * int(repeat)
        char = repeat = ''
    if not token.isdigit():
        char += token
    i += 1
print(output)
```

This outputs:

```
aaaaaaaaaaaatttttiiiiiioorrrrrrrrrrree
```

Comment: hmmm this 2nd condition is what I did not know... if chars are empty ->false? if chars are not empty , simply evaluating them as-is makes them True?!

Comment: Yes, in Python an empty string is considered `False`, while a non-empty string is considered `True`.

Answer (score 3):

Regex is a good fit here.

```
import re
pat = re.compile(r"""
(\w)       # a word character, followed by...
(\d+)      # one or more digits""", flags=re.X)

s = "a12345t5i6o2r43e2"
groups = pat.findall(s)
# [('a', '12345'), ('t', '5'), ('i', '6'), ('o', '2'), ('r', '43'), ('e', '2')]

result = ''.join([lett*int(count) for lett, count in groups])
```

---

Since you can't use regex for some unbeknownst reason, I recommend a recursive function to split the string into parts.

```
import itertools

def split_into_groups(s):
    if not s:
        return []
    lett, *rest = s
    count, rest = int(itertools.takewhile(str.isdigit, rest)), itertools.dropwhile(str.isdigit, rest)
    return [(lett, count)] + split_into_groups(rest)

s = "a12345t5i6o2r43e2"
groups = split_into_groups(s)

result = ''.join([lett*count for lett, count in groups])
```

or, using a more generic (and Functional-derived) pattern:

```
def unfold(f, x):
    while True:
        v, x = f(x)
        yield v

def get_group(s):
    if not s:
        raise StopIteration()
    lett, *rest = s
    count, rest = int(itertools.takewhile(str.isdigit, rest)), itertools.dropwhile(str.isdigit, rest)
    return lett*count, rest

s = "a12345t5i6o2r43e2"
result = ''.join(unfold(get_group, s))
```

Comment: i can't use regex, it should be loops used here

Comment: @ERJAN Regex is the correct tool for the job. Using a loop is incorrect here.

Comment: @ERJAN if you have any kind of restrictions on the thing you're asking a question about, you have to include what those restrictions are. Otherwise people are going to answer the question the correct way, not the "homework" way.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby

text = 'a12345t5i6o2r43e2'

groups = [''.join(group) for _, group in groupby(text, key=str.isdigit)]
result = list(zip(groups[::2], groups[1::2]))

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[('a', '12345'), ('t', '5'), ('i', '6'), ('o', '2'), ('r', '43'), ('e', '2')]
```

Comment: thx u for showing advanced python, but i should use loops here

Answer (score 1):

One of possible variant

```
import re


def main():
    a = "a10t5i6o2r43e2"
    items = re.findall(r'(\w)(\d+)', a)
    return ''.join([letter*int(count) for letter, count in items])
```

Comment: The `+?` quantifier doesn't make much sense after `\w`, because by specification every word character must be followed by digits.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a functional solution using the `itertools` module. You can use the `grouper` [recipe from the `itertools` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) or import via 3rd party [`more_itertools.grouper`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.grouper):

```
from itertools import groupby
from more_itertools import grouper
from operator import itemgetter

a = "a12t5i6o2r11e2"

it = map(''.join, map(itemgetter(1), groupby(a, key=str.isdigit)))

res = ''.join(char*int(count) for char, count in grouper(it, 2))

'aaaaaaaaaaaatttttiiiiiioorrrrrrrrrrree'
```

For reference, the `grouper` recipe:

```
def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx"
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is kind of lengthy, but it works and uses loops as you requested:

```
def parse_segment(string, index):
    for i, letter in enumerate(string[index+1:]):
        if letter.isalpha():
            return string[index+1:i+index+1]
        if i + index + 1 >= len(string) - 1:
            return string[index+1:]

def segment_string(string):
    num_list = []
    for index, letter in enumerate(string):
        if letter.isalpha():
            num_list.append({'letter': letter, 'number': int(parse_segment(string,  index))})
    return num_list

def list_2_string(list):
    ret_string = ''
    for row in list:
        ret_string += row['letter'] * row['number']
    return ret_string

a = "a12345t5i6o2r43e2"
segmented_string = segment_string(a)
result_string = list_2_string(segmented_string)
print(result_string)
```